# Object moves when parented to a bone

Tags: armature, transforms, parent

Select the object, select the bone in pose mode, Ctrl-P, bone, right? So what's the problem?
https://files.fm/f/2d3vnr3q

Comment: Which is the object, which is the bone, which is the problem? Please explain better the issue: in your model some bones are working (with weight assignement, not directly bone assignement), some others not. Which is the problem you need to resolve?

Comment: I'm trying to parent the eyes to the head bone.

Comment: Did you select the object and SHIFT select the bone? They have to be both selected, bone last.